# JavaScript/Coffeescript is not executing unless I refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have some coffeescript:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/9v646/

that utilizes the jquery ui datepicker. On page load it gets an array of available dates (one month at a time) and displays them. This works on IE, but not on firefox or chrome. I have to refresh the page in order to get it to work.

Basically,

```
$ ->
  full_days = []
  partial_days = []
  getDays = (date) ->
     # return the available days for a given month (ajax call)

  getDays()

  formatDays = (date) ->
    # apply a 'full-day' class to days with 24 hours available and 'partial-day' if they have < 24 hours

  availableHours = (day) ->
     # manipulate the json response and make an array

  showdatepicker = ->
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(
     ...
     # make my text field a datepicker
     )
showdatepicker()
```

I tried to just leave bare-bones here, but I can post everything.

**How do I get jquery-UI datepicker to make an ajax call to the db before the page loads AND every time I change the month?**

Edit:

I added some console.log() to the coffeescript. I put one at the very beginning. It appears that the javascript is not executing at all unless I refresh the page (no output unless I refresh).

How do I fix this?

Comment: What specifically does "doesn't work" mean? Anything in the server logs or JavaScript console? Does the `$.get` execute? Does its callback get called? Does the GET request hit your server?

Comment: Sorry. The text field doesn't turn into a calendar, just stays a text field.

Comment: Is your `showdatepicker()` call really outside the `$ ->` or is it really indented along with the rest?

Comment: It should be inside, right? On document load? The  jsfiddle is a copy paste.

Comment: Works fine if you put the `showdatepicker()` call inside and include all the necessary jQuery-UI machinery: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8CYcG/ . Are you certain that you have a `.datepicker` present when you expect it to be? Have you tried a quick'n'dirty `console.log($('.datepicker').length)` check at the beginning of `showdatepicker`?

Comment: I'm not certain, but why would it work in IE and not FF or Chrome?

Comment: I showed you how you can be certain about it. Timing issues depend on all sorts of things including the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was in the Gemfile: turbolinks. Turbolinks was behaving as designed--it was not reloading the page unless I refreshed the page. The reason this worked in my IE browser is when turbolinks fails (old browser) it fails gracefully and allows the pages to be reloaded (I learned all of this from [Rails Cast #390](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?autoplay=true).

All I needed to do was

1. put my code in a variable

   ready = -> 
           (all of my code)
2. call this variable on document ready

   $(document).ready(ready)
3. Tell turbolinks about it

   $(document).on('page:load', ready)